# Use JSON File as a Database with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to use sequalize but not with sqlite , postgres etc. . I want to put my data in JSON file is it possible ? Or is there any library like sequelize which i can use json file as a database ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! There are quite a few npm packages available which suits your requirement.

Here are few for your reference,

**node-json-db** - A simple "database" that use JSON file for Node.js project. - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-db

**disk-db** - A Lightweight Disk based JSON Database with a MongoDB like API - https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskdb

**low-db** - JSON database for Node and the browser powered by lodash API - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lowdb

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot but i think its not possible to use with sequelize ?
I wan to use with sequelize to create data models

Comment: No. Unfortunately, Sequelize ORM is specifically designed to target databases which has transactional, relations support like PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite and MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks then how can i limit data types without sequelize.
For example i want to have an element like user in json and username cant be null and datatype is string

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't achieve these features having a flat file `(.json)` as a data store.